# Truffle Console: If-condition not working

Tags: javascript, truffle-console

In the following code my false condition doesn't work, I have made sample program:

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
module.exports = async function(callback) 
{
   try {
      let keywordStr = '11 =  cccc =        (bbbb sssss )= ttttttttt("")';
      let words =   keywordStr.split(' '); //number of lines in file
      
      for (let i = 0; i <words.length; i++) { 
         word= words[i]
         console.log("word =" + word)
         //NaN = not a number
         if (isNaN(word) === false && word !== null){//if(isNaN(word)==false  && word !== null){
            console.log("testing2 new numeric string = " + word);
         }
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
    }
    callback();
}
```

I just want to print: testing2 new numeric string = 11

but both "false" value and null value not working in the above if-condition:
$ truffle exec findnumeric.js

$ truffle exec findnumeric.js

```
Using network 'development'.

word =11
testing2 new numeric string = 11
word ==
word =
testing2 new numeric string = 
word =cccc
word ==
word =
testing2 new numeric string = 
word =
testing2 new numeric string = 
word =
testing2 new numeric string = 
word =
testing2 new numeric string = 
word =
testing2 new numeric string = 
word =
testing2 new numeric string = 
word =
testing2 new numeric string = 
word =(bbbb
word =sssss
word =)=
word =ttttttttt("")
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved.
Actually I did not know that '' and null are not same things in javascript.

Following link provides the corrected code:
[code forum link](https://codeforum.org/threads/if-condition-not-working.4286/)